# How to remove Radiobuttons from RadiopGroup Created by Array String

Tags: android, arrays, android-radiobutton

I'm new in Android and creating an app that will use RadioButtons for selection and do some work i m able to create RadioButons from String Array and able to get id from selected RadioButtons but now I need to remove the RadioButtons from RadioGroup after selection made

here is code that i m using

```
            for(int i =0; i<ab.length;i++)
            {
                RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
                radioButtonView.setText(ab[i]);
                radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
            }
```

i m able to get map new Array to RadioButtons but not able to remove older Array   (RadioButtons)
Please help so i will continue with my app to go on
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RadioGroup.removeViewAt(int index)` or `RadioGroup.removeView(View view)` or `RadioGroup.removeViews(int start, int count)`

Comment: i would like to pass Array so Radiobuttons will remove

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate?

Comment: i mean to say i would pass array to remove specific number of RadioButtons From RadioGroup so that i will able to remove Specific number of RadioButtons at Once but i will useRadioGroup.removeViewAt(int index)  @Dummy